# How to setup TeamViewer wake up on lan on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wake-on-lan

I wanted to setup TeamViewer on my MacBook Air (2015, macOS Sierra 10.12.1) to wake up on LAN.

Does MacBook allow wake up on LAN (WOL)?

Answer (score 2):

To enable Wake-on-LAN, open System Preferences → Energy Saver and check ‘Wake for Wi-Fi network access’.

Mac uses the standard WoL port 9.

Your setup will work if you have another device on the local subnet to sent the wake packer or if you can take advantage of iCloud and bonjour sleeep proxy so that naother Apple device like Apple TV can send the wake request by proxy.